# Python + Jenkins job gives Result Code = 0 for failed test case

Tags: python, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed on a remote server(not sure what OS it is) 
and python test file which have many test cases( i.e def() )

When i run the Jenkins job  .It gives output on console where  certain test pass and other fails but at the end of the console output it shows:

```
**********************************************************************************************************************************
------------------------------------------------------------
Test complete. Result code = 0
STS: smoke_1
Unlock Code: 2014021009141392041655
------------------------------------------------------------
Archiving artifacts
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
Sending email to: xxx
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: SUCCESS
***********************************************************************************************************************
```

Why is the Result Code = 0 above when some test pass and others fail in the python file,
how can i correct the result code to non zero value?

Is it some error with Jenkins or Python code?

Comment: There are several ways to run python in jenkins, but in the end, the script needs to return a non-zero value for jenkins to recognize it as an error. Either you have a lame test case executor that isn't returning zero or the jenkins script that calls it isn't remembering and returning the bad exit value.

Answer (score 0):

I use Jenkins via browser on windows machine, so not have much idea of terminal commands. But let me tell you the code:

This is my code:

```
print 'result code before subprocess: '
print result_code 
result_code = subprocess.call(command)
print 'result code after subporcess: ' 
print result_code
```

Before subprocess.call(command) result_code is `-1` (default)
after subprocess.call(command) result_code is `0`

where command = 'jenkins/abc.sh'
where abc.sh calls abc.py file from inside it !

Will `subprocess.call(command)` return zero if all `def()` inside abc.py are executed successfully or will it return zero if all `def()` inside abc.py return passed ?

In my case some `def()` passed and some failed but still `subprocess.call(command)` returns zero !
Is this right ?

What if I want `subprocess.call(command)` return non zero if some `def()` failed inside abc.py ?